# fetch with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just copy and post below method from [here](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1#story2) , this is the definition :

```
public IList<Post> PostsForCategory(string categorySlug, int pageNo, int pageSize)
{
    var query = _session.Query<Post>()
                    .Where(p => p.Published && p.Category.UrlSlug.Equals(categorySlug))
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
                    .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .Fetch(p => p.Category);

    query.FetchMany(p => p.Tags).ToFuture();

    return query.ToFuture().ToList();
}
```

But, I'm using Entity framework instead of NHibernate, but EntityFramework doesn't have any definition for `Fetch` or `FetchMany`! How can I do that with Entity framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this through the `Include` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Note, `Include` is an extension method, so you'll have to add `System.Data.Entity` to your using statements before it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated a full project in MVC with NHibernate to Entity Framework. If you have a good logic in your project and keep in mind the next conversions, I believe you can't have problems.

```
ISession ==> DbContext
session.QueryOver<T> ==> dbContext.Set<T>
session.Query<T> ==> dbContext.Set<T>
Query<T>.Fetch() ==> Set<T>.Include()
session.CreateSQLQuery ==> dbContext.Database.SqlQuery
ClassMapping<T> ==> EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
```